# Allow users to enter a variable length list of items in asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I need to let my users enter a variable length list of items into something that looks like a grid view (or a series of standard text boxes stacked vertically). Each item could be a few characters or a few hundred characters long, and I just want them to enter a "sentence", and then tab to the next row, and always having another blank one ready to go at the bottom of the list.

I don't want to save any data to my SQL Server DB until they enter the entire list and then click on a "save all" button.

When they hit the "save all" button they will be given a preview screen where the data will be presented as standard HTML ordered list.

If they confirm/save, then each row of the grid will then be saved as a separate row into my SQL Server database (with an index to remember the order).

What ASP.Net (or Jquery/javascript) UI control would be the best to use in this situation? (i.e. just for the data entry part - the rest I got covered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for something similar to this:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/374_Adding_Multiple_Rows_in_the_GridView_Control.aspx